# Can't get MySQL query to convert to string

Tags: php, mysql

I know I have to convert the query to a string but in this instance where I am viewing files from a directory I can't figure out how to do this. I know it ($result) has to be converted to a string before I can use it. $result is just a slug or a simple entry in the database that represents a folder so the structure would be projects/$results/files.xxx.....

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT projectslug FROM projects WHERE ID=". $ID);

//$path = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);

echo '<ul>'; 
if ($handle = opendir('projects/' . $result)) {

while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
   if (preg_match('/\.jpg$/', $entry)) {
        echo "<li><a href='projects/$result/$entry\n' target=_blank>$entry\n</a></li>";
   }
 }

 closedir($handle);
}

echo "</ul>";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct here:

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT projectslug FROM projects WHERE ID=". $ID);

//$path = mysqli_fetch_array($result3);
```

Why do you commented it out? Use `$result` instead of `$result3` and then you have the value of projectslug in the database in the variable `$path['projetslug']`.

```
$result =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT projectslug FROM projects WHERE ID=". $ID);

$path = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

if($handle = opendir('projects/'.$path['projectslug']) {...
```

BTW: I hope you're escaping the `$ID` if it comes from an external source like `$_POST` or `$_GET`.

Comment: Wow... That was bad.. result3 shouldn't be there and the $path should not have been commented out. Good catch with escaping the ID... Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

$result is a resource Id not the original fetched resultset. You have to fetch it with any of the method provided in php

```
$query =  mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT projectslug FROM projects WHERE ID=". $ID);

$result = mysqli_fetch_array($query);

$path = $result['path_collum'];

if ($handle = opendir('projects/' . $path)) {

   continue......
```